# Determine the cartesian equation of the tangent plane to M in p (mistake(s) were made in solving).

Tags: calculus, linear-algebra, geometry, multivariable-calculus

Given the torus and given the point p $\in$ M corresponding to the parameters $s=\frac{\pi }{4}$ and $t=\frac{\pi }{3}$.
Determine the cartesian equation of the tangent plane to M in p.

$\begin{cases} x=\left(3+\sqrt{2}cos\left(s\right)\right)cos\left(t\right) \\  y=\left(3+\sqrt{2}cos\left(s\right)\right)sin\left(t\right) \\  z=\sqrt{2}sin\left(s\right) \end{cases}$

I almost solved the question but I made one mistake and don't really see where.

Firstly I substituted $s=\frac{\pi}{4}$ and $t=\frac{\pi}{3}$ into the parametric equation.

This gave me

$\begin{cases} x=2 \\ y=2\sqrt{3} \\ z=1 \end{cases}$

I derived the cartesian equation from the parametric equation and got

$F(x,y,z)=\left(3-\sqrt{x^2+y^2}\right)^2+z^2-2$

Next I calculated the partial derivates for $x,y$ and $z$

$\frac{\partial \:}{\partial \:x}\left(\left(3-\sqrt{x^2+y^2}\right)^2+z^2-2\right)=2x-\frac{6x}{\sqrt{x^2+y^2}}$

$\frac{\partial \:}{\partial \:y}\left(\left(3-\sqrt{x^2+y^2}\right)^2+z^2-2\right)=2y-\frac{6y}{\sqrt{x^2+y^2}}$

$\frac{\partial \:}{\partial \:z}\left(\left(3-\sqrt{x^2+y^2}\right)^2+z^2-2\right)=2z$

I substituted $x=2$, $y=2\sqrt{3}$ and $z=1$ and found
$(x,y,z)=(2,2\sqrt{3},2)$

Then I used the equation of a plane to find my answer which gave me

$2(x-2)+2\sqrt{3}(y-2\sqrt{3})+2(z-1)=0$

after simplifying I got

$x+\sqrt{3}y+z=9$

This answer seems to be incorrect and should be

$x+\sqrt{3}y+2z=10$

Does somebody see what I did wrong here?

Comment: Your errors are numerical, in evaluating the numerical value of the gradient of $F$, the expressions you got are correct, but when substituting $x,y,z$ , you should get $\nabla F = (1, \sqrt{3}, 2 )$

Comment: Yes, but I can't seem to find my numerical error.

Comment: The only problem here that I see is that $2z$ should equal $4$, but in my case $z=1$ which would give $2\cdot 1=2$

Comment: No.  $2z = 2 $ not $4$.  In my solution, in your previous problem, the normal vector produced does not have to match the normal produced here from the algebraic equation, it just needs to be proportional to it, i.e. a scalar multiple of it.

Comment: Yeah, but my vector is not proprotional to the one you found

Comment: The one you found should read $(1, \sqrt{3}, 2)$ , while the one I found in the solution of your previous problem is $(2, 2\sqrt{3}, 4)$.  The numbers that you have in your solution should be reviewed carefully.  Once you do that, you'll find that you should get $(F_x, F_y, F_z) = (1, \sqrt{3}, 2) $

Comment: Okay, I now see where I went wrong, seems like I derived wrongly. Thank you.